# JPG batch compression & rename (find -exec, xargs, piping?)

Tags: command-line, find, convert-command

this is my first post so I hope you'll be kind enough to forgive me if I make some formatting mistakes or else. This is one question I've had for quite some time and while looking for answers I have more questions arising. I was trying to find a way to compress pictures in a folder using `convert` in one command.

First I simply tried:

```
convert * -resize 50% Pic.jpg
```

However this returned the compressed pictures named Pic-0.jpg, Pic-1.jpg, etc. (I also tried `$(find ".JPG")` instead of `*` but this is expanded to the same. In order to have the formatting I wanted I tried:

```
convert * -resize 50% Pic_lorez_{1..3}.jpg
```

But this seemed to take the Pic_lorez_2.jpg and Pic3_lorez_3.jpg as input files, not output files. So following the advice of a friend, I tried:

```
find . -name "*.JPG" -exec convert {} -resize 50% {} \;
```

This compress all files under the same name but doesn't allow to put the name I want to these files (for example, Pic_lorez_{1,2,3,4,5,..100}.jpg).

Would xargs make it possible? Something along the lines of:

```
find . -name "*.JPG" | xargs convert ???
```

I couldn't figure out the proper syntax with xargs. I finally tried a direct pipe of find into convert but convert didn't seem to be able to work that way.

Answer (score 8):

`convert` writes to a different image file. To overwrite original image files use `mogrify`.

Single file:

```
mogrify -resize 50% Pic.jpg
```

All `.jpg` files:

```
mogrify -resize 50% *.jpg
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use this one liner:
`for img in $(ls *.jpg); do convert $img -resize 50% $img;done;`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SIZE=50 ; find -iname "*.jpg" | while read line ; do NF="$(echo $line | sed -r "s/(\.jpg|\.JPG)/_$SIZE\1/")" ; convert "$line" -resize $SIZE% "$NF" ; done
```

That's really not just one line. Here's an indented version:

```
SIZE=50
find -iname "*.jpg" | while read line ; do
  NF="$(echo $line | sed -r "s/(\.jpg|\.JPG)/_$SIZE\1/")"
  convert "$line" -resize $SIZE% "$NF"
done
```

You can adjust the value of `SIZE` to any other size, in percentage.

Please notice that after the first run, it will also take the already converted files as input files. You can skip files named like `_NUMBER.jpg` by modifying the find parameter, or you can also store the converted files somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

This script will do it for you!

Save it in a file and make the file executable with: `chmod +x filename`.

```
#!/bin/bash
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
C=0;
DES="./";       # Destination directory

for img in `find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -iname '*.jpg' -type f`
do
    (( ++C ));
    NF="${DES}Pic_lorez_${C}.jpg";      # New file name
    convert $img -resize 50% $NF;
done

# restore $IFS
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

- Change the `./` to the directory where you want to put converted images, by default it will put them in current directory.
- Change `Pic_lorez_` to whatever name you want to give to converted files.

Answer (score 1):

Use GNU Parallel:

```
find -iname "*.jpg" | parallel convert {} -resize 50% {.}_50pct.jpg
```

and get the added bonus of having all your CPU cores work in parallel and thus speed up the process.

10 seconds installation:

```
wget pi.dk/3 -qO - | sh -x
```

Watch the intro videos to learn more: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1