# How can I compress image PNG And JPG images?

Tags: image-processing, png

How can I compress PNG and JPG images by more than 50%?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a handy tool called `mogrify` that enables to do all sort of batch operations with images.

How to reduce quality of photos:

1. Put all of them in one directory.
2. Make a backup of the directory.
3. Open terminal in the folder (typically by pressing F4).
4. Run command `mogrify -quality 60% *` (this will reduce quality of all .jpg, .jpeg, .png images listed in the folder)

Be aware that image files will be replaced by reduced one. Make a backup first just in case you reduced a quality too much.

You can look up more functionality that mogrify provide in `man mogrify`.

To install mogrify, try `sudo apt-get install -y imagemagick`.

Enjoy :)

Comment: The install command is now, `sudo apt-get install imagemagick`

Comment: Better compressed result for me is with `optipng` [ref](https://askubuntu.com/a/1440003/22308)

Comment: For png's [this article](https://medium.com/@duhroach/reducing-png-file-size-8473480d0476) has some discussion of all the various tools.  According to the author, the place to start would be `zopfli` (in Ubuntu 20.04 repo).