# Bulk Quality Conversion of Images (ie Compression)

Tags: command-line, imagemagick, conversion, png, jpeg

```
├── ~/
│   ├── content/
│   │   ├── image01.jpg
│   │   ├── image02.png
│   │   ├── image03.bmp
│   │   ├── text-file.txt
│   │   ├── video.mp4
│   └── ...
└── ...
```

Let's say I want to compress all images in my `content/` directory utilizing ImageMagick's standard `-quality` argument, with defualt settings. To overwrite and replace the files in their folder (caution!) it seems I would use the mogrify command:

```
~/content$ mogrify -quality *
```

but this just yields the following error:

> @error /mogrify.c/MogrifyImageCommand/5730

What's the correct mogrify command? And what will happen to the non-image files (eg `text-file.txt` and `video.mp4`)? Perhaps I should request the individual `mogrify` commands for individual image types (eg jpg, png, bmp, etc.). Or is there a better strategy for salvaging non-image files?

Comment: The `-quality` option needs a value argument ex. `mogrify -quality 75 *` (without it, the first filename in the expansion of `*` will be read as a - likely invalid - quality value)

Comment: @steeldriver thanks that works, but only for images, doesn't seem to work on video (eg*.mp4). Any idea what to do to include both images and video?

Comment: I have used vlc's transcode feature to do that in the past, but I have no idea what are the best tools currently - sorry

Answer (score 0):

Better compressed result for me is with `optipng` [ref](https://askubuntu.com/a/1440003/22308)

Quoted as below

```
# install `$ sudo apt-get install -y optipng`
# see helpful syntax `$ tldr optipng`  # you may need install tldr `sudo apt-get install -y tldr`
optipng \       
    -o7         `# use best compression but quite slow ref. tldr optipng - fastest is w/ -o0` \
    -strip all  `# remove all metadata ref. tldr optipng` \
    *           `# all files or enter /path/to/your.png`
```